# How to fetch data from custom table with select query?

Tags: custom, table

I have three columns in a table named `id`, `wishlist_id` and `type` and I want to fetch `wishlist_id` according to the `type` field into an array

I am using the follwing code:

```
$wishlistId = $mysql->getColumn("SELECT `wishlist_id` FROM `customer_wishlists` WHERE `type`='wishlist'");
print_r($wishlistId);
```

It is giving me only repeated value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT wishlist_id FROM `customer_wishlists` WHERE `type`='wishlist'";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
print_r($rows);
```

**OR**

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT `wishlist_id` FROM `customer_wishlists` WHERE `type` LIKE 'wishlist'";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: Unable to get result if added the where clause. Without where clause works fine.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your WHERE. Maybe you need to escape stuff. @CkMaurya